# How to bind hirarchial array to dropdown list in knockout js?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to bind a collection of observable array to dropdwon list but it is not binding the dropdown list. Can anybody guide me on how this can be achived?

My View model

```
function viewmodel() {
var self = this;
self.Option = ko.observableArray([{
    mealName: "Standard (sandwich)",
    price: 0
}, {
    mealName: "Premium (lobster)",
    price: 34.95
}, {
    mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)",
    price: 290
}]);
self.OptionsArray = ko.observableArray();
self.addOption = function () {
    self.OptionsArray.push(self.Option);
}
}
var vm = new viewmodel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And binding is as below

```
<button data-bind="click: addOption">Add</button>
<!-- ko foreach: OptionsArray -->
<select data-bind="options:Option,optionsText:'mealName'"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is the JS fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Uj8Zt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your binding, you will want to bind against `$data` rather than `Option`, as it will represent the current item from your loop in `OptionsArray`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5JXgK/

Comment: But in my case i have two more span tags in the foreach loop whose values get updated based on the selection in dropdown. I have updated my JS fiddle accordingly
http://jsfiddle.net/Uj8Zt/1/

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, then you might want something more like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Bpmz2/.  Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: That is exactly what i want...Thanks alot.. As a newbie i am finding ko a bit tricky to understand. +1 for fiddle provided